# The method 'toDate' was called on null

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently struggling with an error that appears for just a slight second: My method toDate was called on null. I am using it, to display the date inside of my chat application (only if the current day is not equal to the day before). Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

I know what causes the error: I save the date like this for each message document:
"date": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),

So when I then get the date and use it in my method, it is returning null for a second, because the server needs time. Any idea how to fix this?

```
Container(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                          maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: message["senderId"] == userId
                            ? MainAxisAlignment.end
                            : MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          // if message is the first message of the day, show date
                          index == 0 ||
                                  DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(
                                          messagesSnapshot
                                              .data!.docs[index - 1]["date"]
                                              .toDate()) !=
                                      DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
                                          .format(message["date"].toDate())
                              ? Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
                                        .format(message["date"].toDate()),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              : SizedBox(),

                          Container(
                            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                maxWidth:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                        0.65),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: message["senderId"] == userId
                                  ? Color(0xFFffd04f)
                                  : Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            // show message text and time
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                // Show message text
                                SelectableText(
                                  message["message"],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 5,
                                ),
                                // show time formatted as "hh:mm a" as string
                                Text(
                                  DateFormat("hh:mm a")
                                      .format(message["date"].toDate()),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
```

Comment: add if statement to check if message != null. And where you load data just use setState  to set and show the data. Also you should use some sort of stateManagement package like provider or Bloc that would help you to keep it organized and scalable.

Comment: Could you kindly show me how exactly? Because I tried to add an if statement, but it does not work inside my row.

Comment: add the if statement inside build before return

eg:
return if(messages==null) ? CircularProgressIndicator() : return <your widget stuff>

Comment: if you want to do a check inside row then extract it as a new widget and do the logic there.

Answer (score 1):

you can check it by giving what do display when null

```
message["date"] != null ? DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format((message["date"]).toDate()): "Loading date"
```

Or you could do these check earlier and add some loading spinners...

Comment: I added the null check already in my streambuilder and even added an extra null check to check if the date field inside the document is empty. Unfortunately that did not help. The second solution you proposed, does not work, because the method toDate cannot be applied to a string,

Comment: message["date"] != null ? DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format((message["date"]).toDate()) : "Loading the date"

Think outside the box my dude :p